# Transfer switch cases value to another process with named pipe

Tags: c, named-pipes

In my program, I want to send my switch case value to another process using named pipe "pipeselect". I write the number in the pipe and read the number in another program. But When I run the problem, it cannot show anything when I enter a case value. How can I do this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  char pipeselect[] = "/tmp/pipeselect";
  char bufs[2];
  int fds;
  int select1;

  /* Pipe Creation */
  if (access(pipeselect, F_OK) == -1)
  {
    fds = mkfifo(pipeselect, 0700);
    if (fds != 0)
    {
      printf("Pipe creation error\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  printf("1. Option 1\n");
  printf("2. Option 2\n");
  printf("Please select an option: ");
  scanf("%d", &select1);

  int i = select1;

  switch (i)
  {
  case 1:
    if ((fds = open(pipeselect, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
    {
      printf("Pipe open error\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    write(fds, bufs, i);
    close(fds);

    printf("Option 1 is selected\n");
    break;

  case 2:
    if ((fds = open(pipeselect, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
    {
      printf("Pipe open error\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    write(fds, bufs, i);
    close(fds);

    printf("Option 2 is selected\n");
    break;

  default:
    printf("Wrong Input!\n");
    break;

    unlink(pipeselect);
    exit(0);

  }
}
```

Comment: You write `i` bytes (where `i` is the option the user entered) of your uninitialized buffer `buf` to the pipe. That doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to tranfer the user enterd value to another program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use `write` like this:

```
bufs[0] = i;           // put value entered by user into buffer
write(fds, bufs, 1);   // write 1 byte from the buffer
```

BTW you could narrow down your code like this:

```
...
scanf("%d", &select1);

if (select1 == 1 || select1 == 2)
{
  if ((fds = open(pipeselect, O_WRONLY)) < 0) {
    printf("Pipe open error\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  bufs[0] = select1;     // put value entered by user into buffer
  write(fds, bufs, 1);   // write 1 byte from the buffer
  close(fds);

  printf("Option %d is selected\n", select1);
}
else {
  printf("Wrong Input!\n");
}

unlink(pipeselect);
exit(0);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael! You are helpful...but I have changed the code and run the program again... I still can't get to Option 1 is selected... I don't know why..

Comment: @JeffSon if the post was helpfull you may upvote it or even mark it as "answer". Concerning your program still not running as you expect, you should post a new question.